# Spring data mongodb: query and sort results based on difference of two fields

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Say I have a Collection defined like bellow:

```
@Document(collection = "Item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String mrp;
    private String discount;

    //getters and setters goes here
}
```

I need to find all *items* which are sorted on [mrp - discount] value.

How to express this using [MongoOperations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) is for. Spring Data MongoDB offers `aggregate` via `MongoOperations`.

```java
TypedAggregation<Item> agg = newAggregation(Item.class, 
  project()
    .andExpression("mrp - discount").as("total")
    .andInclude("mrp", "discount", "id"),
  sort(new Sort(ASC, "total")));
```